# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape elements that don't have unique identifiers

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have worked a small amount with web scraping in Python before, but I'm stuck on what is probably a fairly simple problem.

I want to scrape rates from the table on [this page](https://www.fccu.org/Rates/CD-Rates).

I can get things such as individual elements or all of the rates (because they are all listed under the class "fccu__slash", but I can't figure out how to get the results row by row in a usable format.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
FCCU_url = "https://www.fccu.org/Rates/CD-Rates"
FCCU_resp = requests.get(FCCU_url, timeout=3)
FCCU_soup = BeautifulSoup(FCCU_resp.content, "html.parser")
for elem in FCCU_soup.find_all("td"):
    try:
        print(elem.contents[0])
    except IndexError:
        print(elem.contents)
```

This outputs all the information I want but not in a usable format.

Ideally I'd like to be able to only scrape the CDs with terms I'm interested in and have the results output in a format like this (I only care about rates not APYs):

```
['3 Month', '0.65%', '0.75%']
['6 Month', '1.44%', '1.59%']
['2 Year', '2.37%', '2.62%']
```

These are not the specific ones I care about, but once I understand how to do it I'd like to make the adjustments on my own.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: do tds have a structure which we can refer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to get required output:

```
FCCU_url = "https://www.fccu.org/Rates/CD-Rates"
FCCU_resp = requests.get(FCCU_url, timeout=3)
FCCU_soup = BeautifulSoup(FCCU_resp.content, "html.parser")
for elem in FCCU_soup.select("tbody tr"):
    cells = [td for td in elem.findChildren('td')]
    data = [cells[0].text, cells[2].span.text, cells[3].span.text]
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
['3 Month', '0.65%', '0.75%']
['6 Month', '1.44%', '1.59%']
['1 Year', '2.13%', '2.37%']
['2 Year', '2.37%', '2.62%']
['3 Year', '2.27%', '2.52%']
['4 Year', '2.37%', '2.62%']
['5 Year', '2.96%', '3.20%']
['9 Month', '0.95%', '1.09%']
['19 Month', '1.98%', '2.08%']
['2 Year²', '2.27%', '2.52%']
['4 Year³', '2.32%', '2.57%']
['2 Year', '2.27%', 'N/A']
```

Comment: This is about 10 times shorter and cleaner than the workaround I figured out - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Scrape the html table entirely and then process the individual column that you want.

Pandas [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) does a great job of this

First find the table elements

```
tableobject=FCCU_soup.find_all("table")
```

Pass that into pandas

```
data=pd.read_html(str(tableobject))
```

And then pull remove the columns you don't want.

Comment: Pandas does not read the table properly as this creates a nonsensical dataframe that is not representative of the source table at all.

Comment: Hmm, bad HTML in the source page I guess? @Andersson has what appears to be a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

i try with your code and use `itertools` to group answer by 6 element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest
FCCU_url = "https://www.fccu.org/Rates/CD-Rates"
FCCU_resp = requests.get(FCCU_url, timeout=3)
FCCU_soup = BeautifulSoup(FCCU_resp.content, "lxml")
result = []
for e in FCCU_soup.findAll("td"):
    if e.find_all("span"):
        [result.append(sp.text) for sp in e.find_all("span")]
    else:
        result.append(e.text)

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return list(zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue))

print(grouper(result,6))
```

Output:

> [(b'3 Month', b'$500', b'0.65%', b'0.65%', b'0.75%', b'0.75%'), (b'6 Month', b'$500', b'1.44%', b'1.45%', b'1.59%', b'1.60%'), (b'1 Year', b'$500', b'2.13%', b'2.15%', b'2.37%', b'2.40%'), (b'2 Year', b'$500', b'2.37%', b'2.40%', b'2.62%', b'2.65%'), (b'3 Year', b'$500', b'2.27%', b'2.30%', b'2.52%', b'2.55%'), (b'4 Year', b'$500', b'2.37%', b'2.40%', b'2.62%', b'2.65%'), ...